# Magento 2 JS libraries sometimes don't load

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, fotorama

We are currently running a Magento 2.2.6 instance. Sometimes the product gallery breaks with a JS error:

Uncaught TypeError: settings.$elementF.fotorama is not a function

This also happens to other js libraries on the homepage and catalog page. Sometimes we get an error

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).CustomMenu is not a function

IF you hard-refresh/clear your browser cache it works and all the errors disappear for that page, but if you browse the site it will throw the errors again after visiting a few pages.

I have already tried re-deploying the static assets, turning on and off static signing, disabling all extension, disabling all backend caches and changing my requirejs-config.js file to depend and shim jquery

```
var config = {
    deps: ['jquery'],
    map: {
        '*' : {
            'hello' : 'js/custom'
        }
    },
    'fotorama/fotorama': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
}
```

This issue has been posted various times before, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? i am also facing this kind of similar problem like yours

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the dependencies array is not guaranteed to load in order.

You can use a `shim` within requireJS that will let you define dependencies between libraries and export global variables that can be used with other libraries.

Essentially within the `shim`, you can use the **`deps`** property to define libraries that should be loaded before using the included library.

What you have now is close, but it's not within a shim

Try this:

```
var config = {
    deps: ['jquery'],
    map: {
        '*' : {
            'hello' : 'js/custom'
        }
    },
    shim: {
        // export the variable 
        jquery: {
            exports: '$'
        },
        // fotorama depends on jquery
        'fotorama/fotorama': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to put this in your custom theme `Magento_Theme/frontend/layout/default_head_blocks.xml` - `<remove src="jquery.js" />`. RequireJS should take care of jquery, your theme might be calling it somewhere else. Let me know if it works